# Quarkus - programmatically retrieve named JTA datasource

Tags: java, datasource, quarkus, jta

Hi everyone I'm migrating from Wildfly to Quarkus, but unable to understand how to programmatically retrieve a named datasource. Below the code used until now in Wildfly to retrieve `datasourceName` programmatically (datasource `datasourceName` already defined in `application.properties` along with many others)

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put(AvailableSettings.DATASOURCE, datasourceName);
p.put(AvailableSettings.JTA_PLATFORM, JBossAppServerJtaPlatform.class.getName());
p.put("current_session_context_class", "jta");
p.put(AvailableSettings.SHOW_SQL, false);
p.put(AvailableSettings.FORMAT_SQL, false);
// Adding "hibernate.classLoaders" property is critical for this to work with keycloak!!!
p.put(AvailableSettings.CLASSLOADERS, Collections.singletonList(getClass().getClassLoader()));
entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, p);
```

`conf/quarkus.properties`

```
quarkus.datasource.user-store.db-kind=mysql

quarkus.datasource.DATASOURCEA.db-kind=mysql
quarkus.datasource.DATASOURCEA.username=USER
quarkus.datasource.DATASOURCEA.password=PASSWORD
quarkus.datasource.DATASOURCEA.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://HOSTNAME/DATABASE
```

When running such code in Quarkus, exception is thrown

```
The FastbootHibernateProvider PersistenceProvider can not support runtime provided properties. Make sure you set all properties you need in the configuration resources before building the application.
```

given by this [FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java line](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/hibernate-orm/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/hibernate/orm/runtime/FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java#L300)

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private void verifyProperties(Map properties) {
    if (properties != null && properties.size() != 0) {
        throw new PersistenceException(
                "The FastbootHibernateProvider PersistenceProvider can not support runtime provided properties. "
                        + "Make sure you set all properties you need in the configuration resources before building the application.");
    }
}
```

Meaning, no property is allowed.

Tried with

```
Arc.container().instance(EntityManagerFactory.class, new PersistenceUnit.PersistenceUnitLiteral(datasourceName))
```

but throwing

```
WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread: user-storage-jpa) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
```

Any hint on this? Really struggling to find any useful reference to accomplish this. Can find only [injection-based datasources](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#named-datasource-injection).

thanks a lot,
nicola

Comment: Hi, what properties are you not able to set via `application.properties`?

Comment: @geoand I can set them all, but I can't programmatically access the named datasource. In other terms, I cannot get an `EntityManagerFactory` from namesource `A`, `B` or `C` defined in `application.properties` - I can only inject through annotation.

Comment: Have you tried obtaining it programmatically using: `Arc.container().instance(EntityManagerFactory.class, new io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.PersistenceUnit.PersistenceUnitLiteral("A")).get()`?

Comment: thanks @geoand - tried but got exception, updated the Question above with the stacktrace since cannot write much in the comments

Comment: Are you trying to boot Hibernate on your own? If so, that isn't supported

Comment: I'm not, I'm upgrading a Keycloak extension ref. https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/main/user-storage-jpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the following?  It is based on an example from one of the Keycloak Developers

```
MyUserStorageProvider(KeycloakSession session, ComponentModel model) {
    this.session = session;
    this.model = model;
    em = session.getProvider(JpaConnectionProvider.class, "user-store").getEntityManager();
}
```

https://github.com/pedroigor/keycloak-quickstarts/blob/issue-10579/user-storage-jpa/src/main/java/org/keycloak/quickstart/storage/user/MyUserStorageProvider.java#L73

Comment: Just to update this,  the example is also in the official keycloak-quickstart if you use the main branch.  Latest is not updated for some reason.  https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/main/user-storage-jpa

Comment: Only downside of this Quarkus-based approach is that you must maintain `persistence.xml`with all your datasources, while you could avoid this with the JBoss-based one.

Comment: @NicolaBeghin Do you have an example of the other approach when using keycloak-x?

Comment: You can take a look at the code in here https://github.com/nicolabeghin/keycloak-multiple-ds-user-storage